# Why is there a "B" in Sabrina's hand?

Tags: credits, the-chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

I just started Watching *The Chilling Adventures of Sabrina*, and while showing the credits I noticed that there is a "B" in Sabrina's hand when the name of the series shows.

[image: Sabrina holding letter "B"]

They could have used *S*, the starting letter of her name, but why *B*?

Comment: please consider telling why the down votes?

Comment: I think it's kinda obvious (to me at least) that the letter is part of her clothing. Although it was a complete assumption and I did not know the name of her school.

Comment: her one hand was bend, so it looks like she is holding it

Comment: It looks like she's holding books. Unless her hand is massive.

Comment: Her hand is bigger than her head?

Comment: I think there may be some double-entendre at play here.  Judging by the trailers/promos for the series I think the marketing team behind this poster is going for an allusion to "witch with a capital 'B'".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's actually an **initial on her letterman sweater**. [Sabrina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilling_Adventures_of_Sabrina) attends **Baxter** High School.

> Sabrina Spellman, a teenage half-witch who lives in the town of
>   Greendale with her aunts, her cousin Ambrose, and her familiar Salem.
>   Unbeknownst to Sabrina, when she was just a year old, she was taken
>   from her mother, Diana, by her aunts with the approval of her father,
>   Edward. Sabrina was told that her mother died and she hasn't seen her
>   father since she was young. While Sabrina is taught witchery by her
>   aunts at home, **she lives a relatively normal life in public as a
>   cheerleader and student at Baxter High School.** No one, including her
>   boyfriend Harvey, is aware that she is a witch.

Just to clarify, in the United States we sometimes celebrate our schools with various activities, such as sports & clubs by wearing Letterman apparel or [varsity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varsity) clothing. Usually it's a single initial on the front (and sometimes the full name on the back) of a piece of clothing such as a sweater, cardigan, or a jacket. It's very common for those attending a university, but has extended itself to other levels of education, including High School. It's also not unlike soliciting a favorite local, national, or international sports team.

An Example is Archie Andrew from the [pseudo companion] TV series [Riverdale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverdale_(2017_TV_series)) often seen wearing a Letterman jacket, as he plays football for his school, Riverdale High.

[image: Archie Andrews]

Comment: wow, I just started the series and wondered why the *'B'*. I haven't seen her in the sweater.

Comment: I don't think she has worn it yet and I haven't seen her cheer lead either, but the imagery probably is either in part to remind everyone of Riverdale (from the same EPs, exist in the same universe), give a theme of varsity (since she's torn between schools during the first season) and/or perhaps there will eventually be a plot that relates to that outfit at some point?

Comment: I think it's just a typical image of a high school girl.

Comment: I think part of the confusion is that people may not know what a letterman seater is, as that seems more localized to the US. It might help to describe what it is.